# Want to access .class files inside jar without setting classpath , or placing the jar file inside java predefined library?

Tags: java, jar, package, classpath

Use case: the file `a.jar` contains a set of classes that conflict with entries already on the classpath. However there is one class `Abc.class` that does not. I want to load this class (e.g inside Test.java without adding `a.jar` to the classpath to avoid loading any of the other classes.

I looked at URLClassloader, but it seem to operate on a whole jar only.

So the questions are:

- can I reference a single class inside a jar (e.g. in import statement)?
- or: can I add a single class inside a jar to the classpath?
- is there a different approach I should take?

Comment: A jar does not live inside a package.  What do you mean by "package".  You'll need to provide a lot more detail before anyone can possibly help you.

Comment: ”pack2 and pack1 are in the same directory.”  Do you mean the two .jar files are in the same directory?  Perhaps you should edit your question and show the file tree.

Comment: @Jim Garrison Edited the question.

Comment: Generally, the answer to your question is no.  There are some ways to accomplish it, but they involve reflection, which you want to stay away from.  Why do you want to avoid using a classpath?